# Jacoco Coverage Report is displaying excluded folders with 0% coverage

Tags: jacoco

I have attached jacocoagent with my Tomcat server. I am able to get data in `jacoco.exec` and HTML report but I want to exclude some folders from my coverage report. After adding following command, now I can see excluded folders name in my coverage report with 0% coverage.  How can I exclude the following folders from the report.

Are these excluded folders still contributing in total coverage percentage which is 15% at the moment?

I have added following command in my `Catilina.bat` file:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -javaagent:"C:/git/project/jacoco/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=C:/git/project/jacoco/dump/jacoco.exec,dumponexit=true,output=file,append=true,excludes=oracle.* :vm.*"
```

```
Versions:
Tomcat Server : 7
Operating system : Windows
Jacoco : 0.7.6.201602180812
```

Comment: worked for me with `append=false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of JaCoCo involves two steps:

1. gathering of coverage information
2. generation of report

Both can have exclusions. As of today exclusions specified in configuration of agent affect only first step and won't cause automatic exclusion in second step. Why? Because otherwise code that is never executed won't appear in reports. And as stated in [JaCoCo agent documentation](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html) about option "excludes":

> Except for performance optimization or technical corner cases this
>   option is normally not required.

So to really exclude classes from report you should configure step of report generation.

Comment: Thanks for the sol Godin.. it will be helpful if you can provide the implementation as well. bcz i too can see 0% for classes i have excluded .. but i want to remove them from overall list bcz that is ruining my test coverage,...

Comment: @VrajendraSinghMandloi nor you, nor topic starter do not mention how report is generated.
And Tasks? read the "report" task documentation - https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html
Maven Plugin? read "report" goal documentation - https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-mojo.html
Gradle Plugin? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html

Comment: @Godin Anything has changed to your answer? Bcuz I have the same issue where when tried `jacoco-check` I get the wrong stats because of 0% for exclusions.